# Find many rows in Prisma ORM basing on random numbers

Tags: typescript, express, orm, prisma

**Prisma2 ORM**

Hello, is there any way I cant make it shorter? It looks really bad.. I've tried with loops, but it was breaking.

Generating random indexes of cards

```
export const getRandomCards = (cards: any) => {
  let randomCards: number[] = [];
  while (randomCards.length < 5) {
    let card = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length);
    if (!randomCards.includes(card)) randomCards.push(card);
  }
  return randomCards;
};
```

Then I want to send cards basing on previously generated indexes from the array.

```
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

import { getRandomCards } from "./../../../util";

import prisma from "../../../client";

export const getEvents = async (
  _req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  const cards = await prisma.event.findMany();

  if (!cards) throw new Error();

  const randomCards = getRandomCards(cards);

  try {
    const firstCard = await prisma.event.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: randomCards[0],
      },
    });
    const secondCard = await prisma.event.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: randomCards[1],
      },
    });
    const thirdCard = await prisma.event.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: randomCards[2],
      },
    });
    const fourthCard = await prisma.event.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: randomCards[3],
      },
    });
    const fifthCard = await prisma.event.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: randomCards[4],
      },
    });

    res.send({
      cards: { firstCard, secondCard, thirdCard, fourthCard, fifthCard },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }

  next();
};
```

Is doing it like that even a correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the `in` operator in your query.

The problem with your current approach is that it is "very manual". What if you want to query 20 random cards? You can't write 20 cases... (remember, devs are lazy)

```js
const cards = await prisma.event.findMany({
  where: {
    id: { in: randomCards },
  },
})
```

Why do you need to do this?

```js
const cards = await prisma.event.findMany();

if (!cards) throw new Error();
```

I think you can skip it.
What happens if you have 200k records? You'll query the whole table to just... discard the data and then re run 5 queries?

Just run the query I gave you above and maybe you can do a check like "if cards.length === 0" then throw an error.

Also, I would recommend you to:

- rename `randomCards` by `randomCardIds`, same for `getRandomCards` -> `getRandomCardIds` (otherwise one would assume the variable holds a card object whereas it only holds ids.
- rename `event` entity to `card` maybe? It is a bit counter intuitive to read: `const cards = await prisma.event.XXX` . Is it `event` or `cards` ?

Reference:

- https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#in

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! I just needed a hint like this, I was absolutely sure that I'm doing it wrong.